# Can I count the number of HTML elements using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following HTML and CSS

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}




/* The following is not important, for decoration only */

.my-grid .th {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.my-grid .tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: pink;
}

.my-grid .tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  
  <div class="th">H1</div>
  <div class="th">H2</div>
  <div class="th">H3</div>
  
  <div class="tr">A1</div>
  <div class="tr">A2</div>
  <div class="tr">A3</div>
  
  <div class="tr">B1</div>
  <div class="tr">B2</div>
  <div class="tr">B3</div>
  
  <div class="tr">C1</div>
  <div class="tr">C2</div>
  <div class="tr">C3</div>

</div>
```

So far, everything is OK.

The problem is, this grid is dynamic. So sometimes, the HTML might look like this

```
<div class="my-grid">

  <div class="th">H1</div>
  <div class="th">H2</div>
  <div class="th">H3</div>
  <div class="th">H4</div>
  <div class="th">H5</div>

  <div class="tr">A1</div>
  <div class="tr">A2</div>
  <div class="tr">A3</div>
  <div class="tr">A4</div>
  <div class="tr">A5</div>

  <div class="tr">B1</div>
  <div class="tr">B2</div>
  <div class="tr">B3</div>
  <div class="tr">B4</div>
  <div class="tr">B5</div>

  <div class="tr">C1</div>
  <div class="tr">C2</div>
  <div class="tr">C3</div>
  <div class="tr">C4</div>
  <div class="tr">C5</div>

</div>
```

As you can see, the grid is larger, with more columns, and more rows.

Due to the larger size of the table, the following CSS statement should be modified from

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

to

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
```

**Please note I changed the repeat value from 3 to 5.**

Is there a way in CSS that I count the number of columns? For example, I would like the following pseudo code

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(count(.my-grid .th), 1fr);
```

And are there any CSS mathematical ops? For example, the following pseudo statement:

```
count(.my-grid .tr) / count(.my-grid .th)
```

would result in **3** in my second table example.

Those abilities would help in creating a terrific dynamic CSS grid. Thank you.

Comment: you cannot count but you can do it with a combination of selector to create more column (check the duplicate). Let me know if it's not trivial

Comment: @TemaniAfif - This is not a duplicate. I am trying to adjust the table width based on the number of items of the header, not the full table. `nth-child` does not work on a class, they work on the html element.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ew0kr3d5/ or https://jsfiddle.net/ew0kr3d5/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Thanks. But this is not 100% dynamic. In other words, in both examples you provided, I have a max of five columns. What if I want more? Does that mean I have to estimate the max (e.g., 20 columns), and create CSS as such?

Comment: yes because CSS doesn't have any way to count element so you will need 20 CSS declaration to cover until 20 columns (you can easily generate them using SASS)

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Thank you.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I think this should be reopened, and you add your answer, as it will help others. Both answers you provided are different from the ones in the "duplicate" link you provided. The are almost similar, but not the same.